# AWS S3 How to create Policy Only authorized users of this account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I deploy with aws cloudformation is not working

PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
  BlockPublicAcls: true
  BlockPublicPolicy: true
  IgnorePublicAcls: true
  RestrictPublicBuckets: true

Result: `Bucket and objects not public`

Expected: `Only authorized users of this account`

Someone help me please.

Comment: Can you show your template and why it does not work?

Comment: i can, this is my template
https://uppic.cc/v/ViARToixsU5P4MXwZFNme

Comment: Please don't post updated as answers. Also, please don't use screenshots for code. You can paste code as text into code block of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have these setup, and it can be `Only authorized users of this account`

```
      AccessControl: Private
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerEnforced
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: TRUE
        BlockPublicPolicy: FALSE
        IgnorePublicAcls: TRUE
        RestrictPublicBuckets: TRUE
```